# Windows server 2012 Log Off a remote desktop session without locking the screen

Tags: windows, server, desktop

As in title. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have problem, because when you close remote desktop, gui and whole interface is being locked and any gui based applications or my autoit scripts won't work (they are crashing constantly).

I tried using 'tscon.exe' but this works only on windows server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and I resolved it doing the following:

1. Connect to RD to your server with user "A"
2. From the remote computer, connect to RD to localhost to user "B" (create it if necessary)
3. From the new session, run anything you need.
4. Disconnect the FIRST session, with user "A".

In this way, the session running with user "B" will not be locked, and it will continue running your GUI controls.

Answer (score 0):

Log off means the current session (created by logging in during RDP) is terminated. What you want is to keep the Logon Session live but disconnect the RDP.

Why not use AutoLogon to boot into console and run the scripts? However if the screen locks or someone RDPs and disconnects, the problem you are facing will reoccur.

Answer (score 0):

What I have is to keep GUI and whole windows interface alive when i close remote desktop. Session is alive but gui and whole workstation is getting locked everytime I close rd.