# AWS EC2 instance, Access Denied

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, access-denied

I'm running a window 2012 server instance on aws.

**Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base-2018.05.09 (ami-3c0f22d7)**

**Instance Id - i-0cd5e4853062d3e69**

On the instance I'm running a script that does some automation (c#), mouse clicks/ keyboard clicks etc.

The script works fine till I decide to minimize/close the window of the instance.
Once I drop the focus from the instance I get an error on the server:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Can't see the logic behind it, as it should keep working the same way regardless if I focus or even currently logged to the remote desktop isn't it?

Any suggestions?

Code sample -

```
    static public void StayAlive()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindFocusWindow();
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();

        s.Start();
        while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
        }
        s.Stop();
        s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        while (s.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
        }
        s.Stop();

    }

    static private IntPtr FindFocusWindow()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        //Look for chrome and set to top
        foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Google Chrome"))
            {
                hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
                ShowWindow(hWnd, 3);
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //set to topmost
                return hWnd;
            }
        }
        return hWnd;

    }
```

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: Enter your C# code.

Comment: Edit comes in 5 seconds ^_^

Comment: @wrogrammer Code snippet added, these are the functions Im trying to run.

Comment: Are you sure that account on your server has permissions to start that service?

Comment: @wrogrammer Well as mentioned above the script works fine when I'm on the rds window. just when I close/minimize it stops working.

Comment: I know it's pretty obvious, but did you try running it as administrator?

Comment: Yeah I did. Same result... Been told it could be related to some settings that locks the screen?

Answer (score 0):

So... after digging into this, couldn't find a solution that worked using code.

Using the method offered in the link below has solved my issue -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36190639/7210967

Cheers, Ben.